# How to insert user inputs in powershell jobs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-jobs

I have a PowerShell script which starts a background job (it does port-forwarding using kubectl):

```
$forwardjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{kubectl port-forward service/db 7125:7125} -Name "Database Port-Forwarder"
```

This works fine, however every so often kubectl asks for credentials. I am wondering how I could capture and insert some user input in that case?

My idea with the following additional two lines was to wait some time until we have a response for sure, then check the result and if there is a prompt for a password, simply enter it. However, at that point, the job always results in an error (due to the missing input) and the job is completed.

```
$forwardjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{kubectl port-forward service/db 7125:7125} -Name "Database Port-Forwarder"
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$result = Receive-Job -Job $forwardjob
```

So, the question is how can one capture a input prompt and enter it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only way** to respond to interactive prompts presented by an external program in the context of [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) (a PowerShell [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs)) is to **send all responses *ahead of time*, via the *pipeline***.

This is the same technique you'd use to automate responses to the interactive prompts of external programs in *direct* invocation.   However, note that - unlike in direct invocation - you fundamentally cannot respond to interactive prompts *interactively* when using background jobs.

That is:

- You don't get to control the *timing* of when the responses are sent: they are sent to the external program's *stdin* (standard input) stream right after launching the external program.
- You need to anticipate *all* interactive prompts the program may show (if more than one), in the sequence you anticipate, as reflected in the order of the inputs you send.
- Additionally, this technique can fundamentally only work:

  - if the external program reads responses to its interactive prompts *from stdin* (as opposed to directly from the console / terminal).
  - and if the external program doesn't clear its type-ahead buffer before prompting, especially given that it may not prompt until after some other processing has occurred.

Note that external programs may (sensibly) print their prompt *messages* directly to the terminal (e.g., `Enter your password:` ), which means that they will *not* show up in what the background job captures and outputs via [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job).

Here are **self-contained, platform-specific examples** that show the technique: they use the platform-native shell to simulate some processing, then prompt for a "password" and echo the response, which is provided up front via PowerShell's pipeline:
*Perhaps needless to say, providing plain-text passwords this way is a security risk*.

- Windows

```
'somepassword' | 
  Start-Job { cmd /v /c 'echo doing things... & powershell -NoProfile sleep 2  & set /p pass=Enter^ password: & echo You entered: !pass!' } |
  Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

- Unix-like platforms:

```
'somepassword' |
  Start-Job { bash -c 'echo doing things...; sleep 2; read -p ''Enter password: '' pass; echo You entered: $pass' } |
  Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```